# Load 30 years of date data in the date_dimension table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to load the data from 1st Jan 1995 to 31st Dec 2023. What is the correct syntax for that.  Currently with the help of below query I have data only for 3 years(1096 records).

```
CREATE TABLE "DATE_DIM" 
   (    "DATE_KEY" NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT "NN_DATE_KEY" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATE_VALUE" DATE, 
    "DATE_DAY_OF_WEEK" NUMBER, 
    "DATE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "DATE_WEEKEND_FLAG" NUMBER, 
    "DATE_WEEK_IN_MONTH" NUMBER, 
    "DATE_WEEK_IN_YEAR" NUMBER, 
    "DATE_WEEK_START_DATE" DATE, 
    "DATE_WEEK_END_DATE" DATE, 
    "DATE_DAY_OF_MONTH" NUMBER, 
    "DATE_MONTH_START_DATE" DATE, 
    "DATE_MONTH_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE), 
    "DATE_MONTH_NAME" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "DATE_MONTH_ABBR" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "DATE_QUARTER_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "DATE_QUARTER_NAME" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE), 
    "DATE_QUARTER" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "DATE_FISCAL_YEAR" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE), 
    "DATE_DAY_OF_YEAR_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
    "DATE_DAYS_IN_YEAR" NUMBER, 
    "DATE_HOLIDAY_IND" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_DATE_DIM" PRIMARY KEY ("DATE_KEY");



INSERT INTO date_dim 
 SELECT TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'yyyymmdd')) AS date_key,
      TO_CHAR (mydate, 'dd-MON-yyyy') AS date_value,
      TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'D')) AS date_day_of_week,
      TO_CHAR (mydate, 'Day') AS date_day_of_week_name,
      CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'D')) IN (1, 7) THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS date_weekend_flag,
      TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'W')) AS date_week_in_month,
      TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'WW')) AS date_week_in_year,
      TRUNC(mydate, 'w') AS date_week_start_date,
      TRUNC(mydate, 'w') + 7 - 1/864 AS date_week_end_date,
      TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DD')) AS date_day_of_month,
      to_date(to_char(mydate,'MM') || '01' || to_char(mydate,'YYYY'),'MMDDYYYY') AS date_Month_START_DATE,
      TO_CHAR (mydate, 'MM') AS date_month_number,
      TO_CHAR (mydate, 'Month') AS date_month_name,
      TO_CHAR (mydate, 'MON') AS date_month_abbr,
      TO_CHAR (mydate, 'Q') AS date_quarter_number,
      'Q' || TO_CHAR (mydate, 'Q') AS date_quarter_name,
       'Q'
    || UPPER(TO_CHAR(mydate,'Q')
    || '-'
    || TO_CHAR(mydate,'YYYY'))     AS date_quarter,
            TO_CHAR (mydate, 'yyyy') AS date_fiscal_year,
      TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DDD')) AS date_day_of_year_number,
     ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (mydate, 'Y'), 12) - TRUNC (mydate, 'Y') AS date_days_in_year,

   ' ' as DATE_HOLIDAY_FLAG
  FROM ( SELECT TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12), 'yy') - 1 + LEVEL AS mydate
          FROM dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT   TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 24), 'yy')
                                     - TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12), 'yy')
                               FROM DUAL
                             )
       );
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're really asking about the inner select with the `connect by`. For those fixed dates (which only cover 29 years, no?) you can use:

```
  FROM ( SELECT DATE '1995-01-01' - 1 + LEVEL AS mydate
          FROM dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (DATE '2024-01-01' - DATE '1995-01-01')
       )
```

... which generates 10592 records covering 01-JAN-95 to 31-DEC-23.

I'm not sure why you're storing so many things that are repeated and could be calculated on the fly (days in year, for example), and I'd consider making this a view rather than a table - expecially if it turns out you need a rolling window - but you'd need to consider the performance I suppose.

This stood out as odd:

```
      TO_CHAR (mydate, 'dd-MON-yyyy') AS date_value,
```

The `DATE_VALUE` column i your table is a `DATE` type, so you're doing an implcit conversion as part of the insert - you converting a `DATE` to a `VARCHAR` and back to a `DATE`, for no reason; you can just do:

```
      mydate AS date_value,
```

There may be others... and also worth pointing out that the `D` and `DAY` formats depend on your NLS settings.

Comment: +0.01 for the first half and 1.489 for the second. There's simply no need to store the vast majority of this information. It can be calculated on the fly without accessing a table.

Comment: @Ben - well, that's the most specific score I've had *8-) Agree, I'd use a CTE for almost all of it, maybe in a view if you wanted to tuck the `connect by` away; the only useful bit is the holiday flag, but if needed that would make more sense in small table listing only the relevant dates.

Comment: My head had a good reason for it :-). You deserved more than 0.99 for the second half but I can only upvote once so couldn't go as high as 1.5, which would round up. So, you get 1.499, which rounds down to 1. Sorry!

Comment: Such tables are used in dimensional model, especially helpful for BI tools to generate filters. 10592 is not a lot in the grand scheme of things. Substituting your first block of code will do the trick.

Comment: In dimension tables the extra storage associated with the columns is generally insignificant when the "big picture" is considered, and having the data there helps the optimiser make better choices about the number of DATE_WEEK_IN_YEAR equal to 13 (for example), and avoids the need to calculate values many millions of times a day, and allows better definition of dimension objects, and works better with materialized views and query rewrite.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - I'm not used to working in a situation where this would be useful, but I mentioned performance in the answer to try to cover my ignorance <grin>. It looks odd to me, but that doesn't mean it's wrong or inappropriate for the OP.

Comment: I a not getting the correct result of below 2 columns I think the formaula is not yet correct. Can any one fix this formula.     TRUNC(mydate, 'w') AS date_week_start_date,
      TRUNC(mydate, 'w') + 7 - 1/864 AS date_week_end_date,

Comment: @user2547994 - 'not correct' is not helpful. We have no idea what you want to be in in it, or what you're actually getting. Not sure why you're subtracting 4 minutes and 10 seconds though, are you losing data in that gap? Subtracting 1 second (1/86400) would be more normal to mark the week end.

Comment: Alex : Can I have your email ID I will forward my question to your email ID will proper insert statement