# Populate TIME_DIM

Tags: oracle

I want to populate TIME DIMENSION in oracle and the granularity of the table is one min/record. So total records would be 60*24. Please help me to write the insert statement to populate this table

```
CREATE TABLE TIME_DIM (
    TIME_KEY NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT NN_TIME_KEY NOT NULL,
    TIME_DESC VARCHAR2(20),
    TIME_IN24_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
    TIME_HOUR24_MINUTE VARCHAR2(40),
    TIME_HOUR_NAME VARCHAR2(10),
    TIME_MINUTE_AMPM VARCHAR2(10),
    TIME_HOUR NUMBER,
    TIME_HOUR24 NUMBER,
    TIME_MINUTE NUMBER,
    TIME_SECOND NUMBER,
    TIME_AMPM_CODE VARCHAR2(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (TIME_KEY)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TIME_DIM
BEFORE INSERT ON TIME_DIM FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT TIME_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL
  INTO :NEW.TIME_KEY
  FROM DUAL;
END;
/
COMMENT ON TABLE TIME_DIM IS 'The time dimension table support a business need down to the second for every minute in every hour of each day.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_KEY IS 'System generated surrogate key to uniquely identify the time dimension.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_DESC IS 'Time represented as hh:mm:ss with AM or PM.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_IN24_NAME IS 'Time represented as hh:mm:ss as reflected by a 24 hour clock.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_HOUR24_MINUTE IS 'Time represented as hh:mm as reflected by a 24 hour clock.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_HOUR_NAME IS 'The numerical version of the hour followed by AM or PM.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_MINUTE_AMPM IS 'The hour and minute represented as hh:mm followed by AM or PM.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_HOUR IS 'The numerical value of the hour based on a 12 hour clock.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_HOUR24 IS 'The numerical value of the hour based on a 24 hour clock.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_MINUTE IS 'The numerical value of the minute.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_SECOND IS 'The numerical value of the second.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN TIME_DIM.TIME_AMPM_CODE IS 'Indicates whether the time is morning or afternoon.';
```

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort

Answer (score 4):

Isn't this pretty much the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17456400/266304), just with different date format masks? Anyway...

```
insert into TIME_DIM (TIME_DESC,
    TIME_IN24_NAME,
    TIME_HOUR24_MINUTE,
    TIME_HOUR_NAME,
    TIME_MINUTE_AMPM,
    TIME_HOUR,
    TIME_HOUR24,
    TIME_MINUTE,
    TIME_SECOND,
    TIME_AMPM_CODE)
select to_char(t, 'HH:MI:SS AM'),
  to_char(t, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
  to_char(t, 'HH24:MI'),
  to_char(t, 'HH AM'),
  to_char(t, 'HH:MI AM'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'HH'), '00'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'HH24'), '00'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'MI'), '00'),
  to_number(to_char(t, 'SS'), '00'),
  to_char(t, 'AM')
from (
  select trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/1440 as t
  from dual
  connect by level <= 1440
);

1,440 rows inserted.
```

And to check:

```
select * from time_dim order by time_key;

  TIME_KEY TIME_DESC            TIME_IN24_NAME       TIME_HOUR24_MINUTE                       TIME_HOUR_NAME TIME_MINUTE_AMPM  TIME_HOUR TIME_HOUR24 TIME_MINUTE TIME_SECOND TIME_AMPM_CODE
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------------- ---------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------
         1 12:00:00 AM          00:00:00             00:00                                    12 AM          12:00 AM                 12           0           0           0 AM             
         2 12:01:00 AM          00:01:00             00:01                                    12 AM          12:01 AM                 12           0           1           0 AM             
...
      1439 11:58:00 PM          23:58:00             23:58                                    11 PM          11:58 PM                 11          23          58           0 PM             
      1440 11:59:00 PM          23:59:00             23:59                                    11 PM          11:59 PM                 11          23          59           0 PM
```

Most of your columns are unnecessarily wide, incidentally.

---

The `connect by` is generating all the numbers from 1 to 1440, which is the number of minutes in a day. You could see that by running `select level as l from dual connect by level <= 1440`. That's then turned into fractions of a day with the `(level -1)/1440`; the `-1` is so it starts at `0` instead of `1/1440`. So when level is `37`, say, that gives `36/1440`, which is `0.025`.

Oracle [date arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref168) allows you to add a fraction of a day like this onto another date. I'm adding it to `trunc(sysdate)` which gives me midnight this morning, but any fixed midnight would do. That means that `trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/1440` is equivalent to `2013-07-10 00:00:00 + 0.025`, which is `2013-07-10 00:36:00`.

Now the inner select has given me today broken up into 1440 intervals of one minute each. Again, you could see that by running the whole of that inner `select` on its own. The insert uses all of those, formatted as you requested into the various columns. Because the data format masks used don't include the day, month or year we could have used any base date - the date part is effectively discarded in this scenario.

If you wanted to have 86400 intervals of one second each, exactly the same logic would apply, you'd just need to make the inner select generate more, smaller, intervals, which means the `connect by` would need to generate more `level` values. Your format masks are already recording the seconds - they're just all zero at the moment.

---

OK, I give up... to insert all 86400 records, one per second, into an empty table you'd just need to change the two 1440 numbers in the inner select to 86400:

```
...
from (
  select trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/86400 as t
  from dual
  connect by level <= 86400
);
```

Hopefully it's already obvious why.

If the table is already populated with the 1440 one-per-minute records, and for some reason you can't delete them all/truncate the table and start again, you could insert the 59 'missing' records for each minute using the same method, but just excluding the values you already have - those where the `time_second` value is 0, effectively.

```
...
from (
  select trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/86400 as t
  from dual
  connect by level <= 86400
)
where t != trunc(t, 'MI');
```

The filter is excluding any generated times from the inner select where `t` is exactly equal to itself truncated to just the minute. If `t` was `00:01:42`, `trunc(t, 'MI')` would be
`00:01:00`, and you already have a record for that. So, it, and the 1439 others like it, are skipped, and the other 84960 generated from the inner select will be inserted. That gives you all the `time_second` values from 1 to 59.

The `time_key` values will be out of order, but presumably that doesn't matter. If it does then you would have to truncate, and possibly reset the sequence as well before doing the full insert.

Comment: Sorry just slight change. I need to load one record/second. So total record count would be 86400. Can you tweak this script.

Comment: You really can't figure that out after seeing how this and the previous answer worked? It's a trivial change since you're already storing the second value (always as zero). Do you not understand how this works?

Comment: @user2547994 - why do you think most of it needs to change? You already have the seconds stored in `time_desc`, `time_in24_name` and `time_second`; they are just all `00` at the moment. I've added to the answer to explain what the inner select is doing and give you another hint about what needs to be changed.

Comment: @user2547994 - I don't want to just tell you the answer (though I've already come very close, and I'm struggling to understand why it isn't obvious) because you need to understand it and hopefully want to learn, not just be given every solution fully formed. The only wrinkle I can see is, are you trying to insert 59 new records for each row you have already? And if so, do you have to - can't you delete what's there and start again, putting all 86400 in with one statement?

Comment: Now, you catch my point correctly. I need 59 records for each row. Can you tell me how I “putting all 86400 in with one statement”

Comment: @user2547994 - OK, I've added how to generate all 86400 rows in one go, and also how to fill in the 59 missing seconds for each minute if you already have the original 1440 rows.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. I really appreciate your help Alex.

Comment: @user2547994 - OK. You might want to delete the [new question you asked about this earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17576521/266304). This might also be a good time to remind you about [how to show appreciation for answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).